# Closed set, closure of a set

Tags: general-topology

Prove  if A is open then $A \cap   \bar{B} \subset \overline{A \cap B}$

$ A \cap   \bar{B}= A \cap (B \cup B')=(A \cap B) \cup (A \cap B')$

$A \cap B \subset \overline{A \cap B} $ then I have to show that $A \cap B' \subset \overline{A \cap B} $

I don't know how to prove it

Comment: Use the \overline{} feature of $\LaTeX$ instead of \bar{}. I edited your post and did one so you can see how it looks.

Comment: Use the fact that $A$ is a neighborhood of each of its points.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't known how use this fact. Can I have some help?

Answer (score 1):

If $b \in B'\setminus B $ a limit point then if $b \in A$, then for every nbd $U$ of $b$ intersects $B$ at a point and since $A$ is open and $U$ open and since $A \cap U$ is non empty ( contains $b$ ) it has a point other than $b$, ( what if $A \cap U = \{ b\}$ ? ). As a result $b$ is a limit point of $A \cap B$.

Answer (score 0):

if $b \in B'\setminus B$ is a limit point, $A$ is open and $b \in A$ then $A$ is a nbd of $b$ thus $(A \setminus   \{b\}) \cap B \not = \emptyset $ therefore $b$ is a limit point of $A \cap B$

Thank you for your help